# How to check to ensure you have an integer before calling atoi()?

Tags: c, casting, atoi

I wish to take an integer as a command line argument, but if the user passes a non-integer string, this will cause a stack overflow.  What is the standard way to ensure atoi() will be successful?

Comment: atoi shouldn't stackoverflow --are you sure?  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 24):

You can use:

`long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`

Then check if `*endptr != nptr`. This means that the string at least begins with the integer.
You can also check that *endptr points to terminating zero, which means that the whole string was successfully parsed.

Comment: Just to add that strtol() also modifies "errno". You will know if the integer is too big to fit a "long". Also, as Lou Franco said, atoi should not cause a stack overflow. In that case, your string must use unallocated memory.

Answer (score 4):

`atoi()` will (should) not cause a stack overflow if the string contains characters other than digits. It will simply convert to an `int` any digit it finds from the beginning of the string until there is no more.

```
  int x = atoi("12monkeys"); // x is 12
  int y = atoi("monkeys12"); // y is 0
```

You may check that there is no *integer overflow* (number outside the range of [-2^31, 2^31-1] on a modern (current) PC architecture).

**edit** (comments)

While the C standards warns about an *undefined behavior* if the value cannot be represented, the most common C recent compilers (gcc, MS...) do not *crash* if the value is not acceptable (unless the `char *` pointer is null or wrong of course).

Anyway, you can implement your own `atoi()` easily (with the same limitations as in my answer)

```
    #include <ctype.h>

    int myatoi(char *s) {
       int res = 0, minus = *s == '-';
       if (minus) s++;

       while (isdigit(*s)) {
          res = res*10 + (*s++ - '0');
       }

       return minus ? -res : res;
    }
```

Comment: C99 §7.20.1/1, "The functions `atof`, `atoi`, `atol`, and `atoll` need not affect the value of the integer expression `errno` on an error. If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: KennyTM is correct. In principle, `atoi("123456789101112131415");` could crash the program or do anything, since it's specified as UB.

Answer (score 3):

This does not cause stack overflow. `atoi` returns `0` if it can't find a number at the start of the string. Your (non-)handling of the `0` is what causes the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Cause a stack overflow? Well I suppose that's one possible result of the *undefined behavior* if the value in the string overflows the range of `int`. In practice though it usually just wraps or returns a bogus result.

If you want better error checking, use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. It has well-defined behavior on overflow (it sets `errno`, which you need to clear to 0 before calling `strtol` so you can distinguish between error returns and legitimate values being returned) and you can examine the point in the string at which it stopped conversion to see if the full string was an integer or whether there's additional content past the end.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi()` is converting the string to an integer if it contains only digit chars, otherwise it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a standard atoi will stackoverflow, but there's no way to tell if you don't have an integer with it.  Use `strtol` instead -- it's possible to deal with non-integers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtol

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Check [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) available in stdlib.h

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do this and enter Undefined Behavior land, you could write a simple validation function like so:

```
/* returns 0 on success, 1 on failure. */

int verify(char * string)
{
    int x = 0;
    int len = strlen(string);

    while(x < len) {
           if(!isdigit(*(string+x)))
           return 1;

           ++x;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note you do have to call this function *before* you call atoi(), and you need string.h and stdio.h.

Comment: How does this prevent undefined behavior due to a potential integer overflow? The number could still be way too big to be represented in an int or any other standard integral data type.

Answer (score 0):

To check for overflow, you can simply convert the number you got from `atoi` back to string. Now compare this string with your input string. If they match, then it's not an overflow, otherwise it is.

See a psuedo code here:

```
int check_overflow(int num, char *arr, int len){
    char buf[len + 1];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", num);
    if(strcmp(buf, arr) == 0){
            return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The function returns -1 if its an overflow else 0.