# Convert returned char to int

Tags: c

I'm trying to work with C for the first time. I have a program that calls a bash script. This script `printf`'s a number via

```
COUNT=$(ls | grep tool | wc -l)
printf "%s" "$COUNT"
```

I want to grab this number and perform a simple math operation on it. However, I can't seem to be able to convert this value into an `int` so that I can divide it by 2.

I've tried things like https://stackoverflow.com/a/868508/183254

```
int myint = otherint - '0';
```

which produces a segmentation fault when I got it to compile and it attempted to do the math.

I've also tried many iterations of

```
int cc;
cc = count - '0';
// warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
// or
// warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

to no avail.

I've read several posts that came up for the google search for those errors, but still can't seem to be able to wrap my head around what is going on I think perhaps because I don't have the context of what the questioner is trying to achieve.

Here is a little demo I put together to try and understand what is going on. Turns out it just made me more confused.

```
int main(){
  char *x;
  x="44";
  int xx;
  xx = (int) x - '0';
  printf("x is : %s\n", x);
  printf("xx is : %d\n",xx);// x is : 23703288
  char command[64];

  char path[9];// won't work if set to <=8
  int status;
  FILE *fp;

  //this shell script just counts the number of files in a directory
  //that match a certain string. 
  strcpy(command, "/test/test.sh");// returns 0-9; in this case it's returning 4 (supposed to anyway)


  fp = popen(command, "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;

  while (fgets(path, 9, fp) != NULL) //again, won't work if arg2 is <=8
    //printf("%s", path);

  status = pclose(fp);

  int cc;
  cc = (int) path - '0';

  printf("result of path is %s\n",path );    // result of path is        4
  printf("result of conversion is %d\n", cc);// result of conversion is 1582717056
}

output:

x is : 44
xx is : 182607602
result of path is        4
result of conversion is 1423813191
```

I've found and read a couple of primers but I don't know if they are old or what but the didn't help much besides explaining pointers a bit.

What really boggles my mind is what is going on in the snippet above:

```
x is : 44
```

Ok, that makes sense since I typed out `x="44";`.

```
xx is : 182607602
```

wat. This looks like it must be a pointer to some address. According to the primers I read, this should come from something like `&x;`; why is it coming from what should be converting the `char 44` to `int 44`?

```
result of path is        4
```

Ok (except all of those spaces). It almost seems like it's being padded or something. `char path[9];` and `while (fgets(path, 9, fp) != NULL)` heighten my suspicion, but as commented won't work <= 8.

```
result of conversion is 1423813191
```

Same; seems to be pointing to address space. Don't understand why.

It seems to be a point of confusion for many people (including me) coming from other languages -- that's my excuse and I'm sticking to it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated (good primers, what's going on in this code, anything really).

Thanks.

---

Found an excellent 9-part series on youtube which does a great job explaining some C fundamentals:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkB3phqR3X40reMCBYSoNUPbDvM4kybMs. Part 7 was especially useful -- it covers pointers which was a big part of my confusion.

Comment: x is a `char *`, not a `char`. Your `- '0'` trick only works on a char.

Comment: You should read a beginner C tutorial and/or book before attempting to do similar tasks. The function you are looking for is called `strtol()`; **however,** you must possess a minimal understanding of the C type system in order to be able to make sense of its use (and others).

Comment: @H2CO3 which is why I asked at the end for pointers to good current primers (or anything else). Thanks, though.

Comment: @Random832 incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [3]'

Comment: @stormdrain I was _not_ telling you to make it a char. I was simply telling you that solutions designed for a char won't work on strings.

Comment: @Random832 ah, ok. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char *x;
  x="44";
  int xx;
  xx = (int) x - '0';
```

Here you are subtracting `'0`' from a *pointer* by casting it to an int. This logic would work if `x` is of type `char`.

What you really want is to convert the string into using **[strtol()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strtol.html)** or related functions.

In the same way, you can convert `path` to integer as well, which you do later in your code.

Comment: Isn't `x` of type `char` though? Or is `x` of type pointer in this case? I think this is a big part of my confusion. Instantiating a variable with `char *x` means what? It will point to something? It *is* pointing to something? When called, will return the address?

Comment: No. `x` is type `char*` i.e. a pointer to char. When you assign `"xx"` to `x` (as in char *x; -- too many x's around ;-) you are assigning the address of the string literal (which is same as the address of the first `x` in `"xx"`).

Comment: So, you mentioned I converted `path` to `int` later in the code (`cc` I assume). Why then does `cc` print what looks to be an address pointer (1423813191)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help (and patience with all the `x`'s) :) Was there supposed to be a link though? I don't see anything by or on "You can read more here" or were you referencing the other answer here?

Comment: Yes, I talk about cc. The exact problem that happens with x also happens with path as well. Though path is of different type (char[] i.e. array of chars), it's converted to char* when you use it in an expression like path - '0'. path[] becomes char * in few other occasions too. But that's not so relevant here. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Answer (score 1):

Where you are using this line to convert a two digit number to an integer:

```
xx = (int) x - '0';
```

try changing it to

```
xx = atoi(x);
```

Here is a good reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

To go the other way you may like sprintf

```
sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);
```

where you can find more information here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: The problem with `atoi()` is that it doesn't report any errors on conversion failure.

Comment: Yes, you have to clean your own data.  Looping through with isdigit should do the trick.  here is a handy link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850558/how-to-check-to-ensure-you-have-an-integer-before-calling-atoi

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
xx = (int) x - '0';
```

and line from mentioned post:

```
int i = c[0] - '0';
```

are not the same. You subtract from a pointer but in the post '0' is subtracted from char. In your case the correct version is (without any checks):

```
xx = x[0] - '0';
```

or as in post above - you have to convert (char*) to an int with any standard function