# How can I convert char* to int?

Tags: c++

I have the array of the arrays of `char`. I need to convert it into an array of `int`. How can I do that? I know we can convert `char*` to `int` as follows:

```
char *i = "123";
std::stringstream ss;
ss << i;
int ii;
ss >> ii;
std::cout << ii << std::endl; //prints 123
```

But how can I convert the array of such an arrays into an array of integers?

Comment: You mean something like [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, using the stringstream is a legacy way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [atoi()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) function already present.

It will convert the string into a integer that you can use.

Comment: I've heard that we should try to avoid using that function...

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850558/how-to-check-to-ensure-you-have-an-integer-before-calling-atoi)

Answer (score 1):

```
char* strings[4] = { "123", "456", "789", "555" };
int vals[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << strings[i];
    ss >> vals[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    std::cout << vals[i] << std::endl;
}
```