# C: Check if a string is an integer and save it

Tags: c

I've been searching the internet for some time, but didn't find a simple solution for a actually simple problem in my eyes. I guess it has been asked already:

I'm reading a value like `20.1` or `XYZ` via `sscanf` from a file and saving it in `char *width_as_string`.

**All functions should be valid in `-std=c99`.**

Now I want to check if the value in `width_as_string` is an integer. If true, it should be saved in `int width`. If false, `width` should remain with the value `0`.

My approaches:

```
int width = 0;
if (isdigit(width_as_string)) {
    width = atoi(width_as_string);
}
```

Alternatively, convert `width_as_string` to `int width` and convert it back to a string. Then compare if it is the same. But I'm not sure how to achieve that. I already tried `itoa`.

Functions like `isdigit` and `itoa` are not valid in `std=c99`, therefore I can't use them.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think is "integer" here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check to ensure you have an integer before calling atoi()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850558/how-to-check-to-ensure-you-have-an-integer-before-calling-atoi)

Comment: @MikeCAT 20.1 is not an integer, is it? The values in width should only contain digits from 0-9 :)

Comment: So isn't `-123` considered as integer here?

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh forgot to mention: `-123` could be considered as an integer but it would filtered out afterwards. Only numbers within the range of 20 and 40 are going to be accepted.

Comment: `isdigit` most certainly is valid in C99.  `itoa`, not so much.  Use `strtol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read *carefully* some [documentation of `sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It returns a count, and accepts the `%n` conversion specifier to give the number of character (bytes) scanned so far. Perhaps you want:

```
int endpos = 0;
int width = 0;
if (sscanf(width_as_string, "%d %n", &width, &endpos)>=1 && endpos>0) {
  behappywith(width);
};
```

Perhaps you want also to add `&& width_as_string[endpos]==(char)0` (to check that the number is perhaps space suffixed, then reaching the end of string) after `endpos>0`

You could also consider the standard [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which sets an end pointer:

```
char*endp = NULL;
width = (int) strtol(width_as_string, &endp, 0);
if (endp>width_as_string && *endp==(char)0 && width>=0) {
  behappywith(width);
}
```

The `*endp == (char)0`  is testing that the end of number pointer -filled by `strtol`- is the end of string pointer (since a string is terminated with a zero byte). You could make that more fancy if you want to accept trailing spaces.

PS. Actually, you need to specify *precisely* what is an acceptable input (perhaps by some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) syntax). We don't know if `"1   "` or `"2!"` or `"3+4"` are (as C strings) acceptable to you.

Comment: Suggest `if (endp != width_as_string &&  ...` to detect `"   "`.

Comment: @chux: unless `width_as_string` is *starting* with a non number character (like `/`) it is often the case that `endp != width_as_string` so that test might not bring much.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Second one works great, thanks!

Comment: 1) The `if (endp` test does not provide anything that I can see. `strtol()` converts a string and when the function is done `endp` will point to someplace in that string, so `strtol()` will not form a `NULL` valued `endp`.  2) This answer accepts `width_as_string` when it is `""`.

Answer (score 1):

How about strtol?

This gives a clear return value if something goes wrong, i think this is what you're looking for

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not successful implementing this function :(

Comment: @michithebest What do you mean by implementing ? It is a standard function , you have to use it .

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could use sscanf at the very beginning to check whether the number is integer or not. Something like this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int 
 main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int wc; // width to check
    int w; // width

    char *string = "20.1";

    printf("string = %s\n", string);

    if (strchr(string, '.') != NULL)
    {
        wc = 0;
        printf("wc = %d\n", wc);
    }
    else if ((sscanf(string, "%d", &w)) > 0)
    {
        wc = w;
        printf("wc = %d\n", wc);    
    } else w = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

This is a sample program of course, it first searches the string for a "." to verify if the number could be float and discards it in such a case, then tries to read an integer if no "." are found.

Changed thanks to ameyCU's suggestion

[Reference page for sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf)

Comment: Tried it like this `if ((sscanf(width_string, "%d", &width_to_check)) > 0) {
    width = width_to_check;
   } else width = 0;` but it is accepting values like `20.1` and just chops them down to `20` :(

Comment: @michithebest Before reading value in variable , check if there is `.` present in the string using maybe `strchr` , or `strstr` functions .

Comment: But is it going to still work if the value is `20,1` or `20abc`? In both cases `width` should remain `0`

Comment: No, as it is now it still has those problems, so this isn't the correct answer :(